# Are there open complete usenet archives?

Tags: data-request, internet

Are there any open complete and downloadable usenet archives?

I don't expect binaries to be included, only the text messages? If the complete archive is not available, than at least a partial archive of some categories? But the most interesting aspect for me is, if there are complete archives for at least a part of groups, so containing all posts from beginning until now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check out [Exploring the USENET Archive: Early Thoughts](http://ianmilligan.ca/2013/03/06/exploring-the-usenet-archive-early-thoughts/) and [here](http://archive.org/details/utzoo-wiseman-usenet-archive) is archive.org's archive.

Comment: Google Groups no longer appears to support search by author, archive.org's archive is not really searchable, and both are very incomplete, e.g. from the latter, [comp](https://archive.org/details/comp) has been removed. I suspect fully public and searchable archives may never reappear due to privacy concerns.

Answer (score 3):

> Google's been hosting all the Usenet archives for some time.

Most of Google's archive only goes back to ~1990 - their oldest stuff is from 1986.

The Usenet Archive (http://www.crunchbase.com/company/the-usenet-archive) is more complete, going back to ~1980 - which technically was the beginning of the nn protocol "usenet".  But the really old email based listserv archives seem to be gone.

[Someone has edited-swiped my answer.  I don't believe the above information is true, google has been hosting the USENET archives all the way back since their inception -- something like 1975.  --markj]

Comment: If you're going to mention GoogleGroups, you have to mention that it pre-dates Google, as it was originally [DejaNews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Groups#Deja_News) ... and there has been significant complaints about how Google handles the archival nature of GoogleGroups vs. newer posts.

Comment: Thanks, feel free to make a new answer, I will remove mine.

Comment: Is there any way to download a full copy of either of these archives, or are they only exposed via search?